# Netbeans 7.2 dark theme doesn't highlight the class variables properly

Tags: themes, netbeans-7

My favorite Netbeans theme is Norway Today. Like the default white theme, it used to highlight the global and class variables green. Now it doesn't. The default theme still works fine. I tried this on both of my computers. I also have another computer which have NB 7.0 and it highlights properly. Here are the screenshots

Default Theme

[image]

Norway Today

[image]

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can always customize it.

Go to `Tools -> Options -> Fonts & Colors`.

Then select the Norway Today theme and select Java in the language section.

In the category section look for Field Declaration and Field Use and change the current Foreground value to the color you like. I suggest using RGB: 0, 153, 0 to give it a nice green touch.

Norway Today is also my favorite theme and I still wonder why they changed it.

**EDIT:**

Another option could be exporting the theme from NB 7.0 and importing it to NB 7.2, however I have not tried that approach.